# how to display a specified value from an multidimensional array in twig template

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I tried to display the service name from the array `service`. But I did not get the all names. In twig template it only shows the last entered name. Any one help me to solve this. Here is my code:

```
$data['service'] = array();

$sql= "SELECT * FROM services";

   $serviceDetails= mysql_query($sql);

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serviceDetails, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$data['service']['name'] = $row['service_name'];
$data['service']['id']= $row['service_id'];

}

echo $twig->render('test.html',$data);
```

In twig template,the code is,

```
<ul>
    {% for  service_name in service %}
        <li>{{ service_name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I need to get the names only. But only last entered name is displaying.

Comment: service.service_name may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your array `$data['service']` with every loop pass in the PHP. I'm not quite certain what you want to see, but I expect the twig will work if you change the PHP to this:

```
$data['service'] = array();

$sql= "SELECT * FROM services";

$serviceDetails= mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serviceDetails, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    $data['service'][]=$row['service_name']

}

echo $twig->render('test.html',$data);
```

Comment: In above code only service_name is fetching.I want service_id also..How can i change the code for fetch both service_name and service_id.

Comment: Then the `services` variable needs to be an  array of arrays. I'll post it as a separate answer, since it's quite different from the above.

Answer (score 0):

To get both values into your twig, build `$services` as an array of arrays. Associative arrays tend to be the easiest to understand.

Step one, build the data structure:

```
$data['service'] = array();

$sql= "SELECT * FROM services";

$serviceDetails= mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serviceDetails, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    //Place both name and service_id in the array
    $data['service'][]=array('name' => $row['service_name'], 'id' => $row['service_id']);
}

echo $twig->render('test.html',$data);
```

Step 2: Read that data back in twig:

```
<ul>
    {% for  service_data in service %}
        {# service now contains both the id and name as separate elements #}
        <li>{{ service_data.id}}: {{ service_data.name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: @Reshma I'm glad! Can you accept the answer then please?